# What is the mechanism of aldol condensation between two diketo-compounds with sodium bicarbonate?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, reaction-mechanism, aldol-reaction

> In particular, what is the mechanism of aldol condensation of dimethyl-1,3-acetonedicarboxylate and 2,3-butanedione with sodium bicarbonate?

I'm trying to work out the mechanism of this aldol condensation using aqueous sodium bicarbonate as a base. I came up with this following mechanism:

[image: My mechanism for the reaction]

However, I showed this to a Ph.D. student and they said that because the solution is aqueous the bicarbonate would form carbonic acid, a very weak acid which would be unstable and decompose to $\ce{CO2}$ and $\ce{H2O}$. I know this reaction can occur with this base but now I don't know how the mechanism works if it isn't in the way outlined below. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: If the carbonate forms carbonic acid some other species has to remain as a sodium salt. That species is basic.

Comment: Ask another PhD student, or maybe just measure the pH.

Comment: Your final product is missing the double bond in your proposed mechanism.

Comment: @KarstenTheis You're right my mistake, other than that though does the mechanism make sense?

Comment: I agree with  Karsten Theis and Waylander in their comments. Also, nothing wong with asking your teacher for his/her opinion. Keep in mind that your reaction is not completed (also you forgot the double bond at the end). It is thermodynamically possible to eliminate another water molecule to give much stable product.

Comment: Was that a Chemistry PhD student you asked?

Comment: The mechanism makes sense to me, but I'm a biochemist. I'm pretty sure about acid base chemistry, but not so much about organic synthesis (my track record in the lab was mixed).

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne This is only the first step of this reaction, a michael addition reaction follows during which the water is lost anyway. It may be lost before that as you say but I don't know how I'd go about working that out since the reactions all happen in one solution.

Comment: I think you basically have the mechanism right, one or other of the -OH groups is eliminated to form the double bond, could be the first one, could be the second.

Comment: With the double bond in place in your final product, elimination of a second equivalent of water is less likely owing to the formation of an unstable cyclopentadienone. If formed they tend to dimerize in a Diels-Alder fashion.